# Boolean array getting unexpected default values

Tags: c++, arrays, breadth-first-search

I wrote the following C++ program to implement breadth first search to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bfsshortreach) problem of finding shortest path for all the nodes from the source.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string.h>
#include<queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int test;
    cin >> test;
    while(test--)
    {
        int m,n,source;
        cin >> n >> m;
        bool visited[n+1];
        int dist[1001];
        queue<int> q;
        memset(dist, -1, sizeof(dist));
        vector<int> adj[1001];
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            int a, b;
            cin >> a >> b;
            adj[a].push_back(b);
            adj[b].push_back(a);
        }
        cin >> source;
        dist[source] = 0;
        visited[source] = true;
        q.push(source);
        while(q.size())
        {
            int v = q.front();
            q.pop();
            for(int i : adj[v])
            {
                if(!visited[i])
                { 
                    q.push(i);
                    dist[i] = dist[v] + 6;
                    visited[i] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if(i != source)
            {
                cout << dist[i] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

It works well if the value of test is 1, but when the value is 2 or more, some values of the boolean array "visited" become 1 in the second and later iterations. I do not understand why and how it happens as I declare the boolean array in every iteration and the default value for its elements is 0. Can somebody please explain this.

Comment: Variable length arrays (such as your `visited`) are not valid C++, although some compilers accept them as an extension..

Answer (score 3):

> I declare the boolean array in every iteration and the default value for its elements is 0.

No, it's not 0. There are no default values for C++ simple types. My bet is you propably get some random values, as your array isn't initialised automatically.

Comment: Thank you, since the values of the elements were zero in the first iteration, I assumed it to be the default value.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't initialising the array, and local arrays are not zero initialised, so explicit initialisation is needed.